# Send JSONObject and to receive a JSONArray using volley

Tags: android, json

I´m using volley to send a JSONObject to the server of my application, I was looking for how to catch a JSONArray as request, but I can put "Response.Listener.JSONArray", it doesn´t work.

Right now I have this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
url, obj,

new Response.Listener <JSONObject > () {@Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        //only for test.
        Log.d("SendRequestJsonPost", response.toString());
    }

}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

}
```

Ok, when I send a JSONObject to the server, I wait to receive a JSONArray, but when I change from JSONObject to JSONArray I get errors on my code.

Someone knows how to do this?

Comment: I had the same problem, check this out.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888485/how-i-send-a-jsonobject-and-recive-a-jsonarray

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, obj,
    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    //only for test.
    Log.d("SendRequestJsonPost", response.toString());
    }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    }
```

Comment: @LeonardoCavani You have used JsonObjectResponce class, you should JsonArrayRequest... Line 5 according to your screenhshot